# ReCreated a Content Type but it does displayed

Tags: nodes, database

I seem to have run in to a problem when re-creating a Content Type, I had a Content Type called Gallery on my drupal 7.32 site, I then deleted it, but then wanted to create it again. When I re-created it , it says its saved but it does not appear in the Content Type list (Under Structure/Content Types), and therefore I cant add content to it. I did receive undefined index errors relating to Gallery when I created it (also shown under Reports/Field List), and went into the database and deleted the rows in Field_Config_Instance table as recommended on #5 item [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1351506)  (delete occurences of rows which have Bundle field = Index). I have worked around this by creating a content type with a slightly different name, which works fine and no errors, but just wanted to know why I could not see a recreated Content Type (in case I have future problems)? I have flushed cache and run Cron, but that didnt resolve the problem. In fact Cron failed, but I reran again and it now works.

Comment: Have you created the gallery content type manually or by installing some module it was created?

Comment: Hi , i created it manually.